# WFS 2.0 with get request outputformat gml3 returns body using wfs 1.1.0 schema, is this expected?

Tags: wfs, gml

I am making GET requests against a wfs service specifying version 2.0, when I do not specify an outputformat in the request it returns a body using the schema namespace for wfs 2.0 (wfs:), when I specify outputformat=GML3 it returns a body using schema namespace for wfs 1.1.0 (gml:)

I know that in the get capabilities it states that it supports gml3.2, gml3, gml2 and that these are largely associated with wfs 2, 1.1 and 1 respectively but I was wondering whether the use of a previous wfs version schema in return body was expected behaviour in this scenario as I wasn't expecting it and I can't find any real info on this.

Comment: I believe that the server is GeoServer and it behaves just that way. I do not know if it is right or wrong.

Comment: WFS has no concept of REST, please include the full requests you are making

Comment: @IanTurton so the request are being made against an arcgis server and is a GET REST request in KVP format; obviously can't include the whole server url but the query params are ?service=wfs&version=2.0.0&request=GetFeature&outputformat=GML3&typenames=TopographicPoint

Comment: It is **NOT** a REST request - it is a KVP WFS request, what happens if you try with POST and an XML file?

Comment: @IanTurton ok...it is a WFS KVP request, it's being made against an arcgis server rest endpoint so just assumed it was a REST request, apologies. POST produces same results.

Comment: Please [edit] the question with all the parameters used and the xml file and (at least) the headers of the response document.